# MxN matrix with ones and zeros following a specific rule

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to create a MxN matrix as shown below:

```
[1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0;
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0;
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1]
```

I have window size, let's say, 5 and it moves 3 in every row. Is it possible to create such a matrix without using `for` loops? Or is there any optimum way to do it?

Comment: for larger M and N, it takes a lot of time to create such matrices.

Comment: make a zeros matrix and change its 5 elements in a for loop. That cannot be slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a one line solution:

```
reshape([reshape([ones(5,6);zeros(21,6)], 1,[]), ones(1,5)],[],7).'
```

note:

The desired matrix  can be seen as concatenation of a `[6, 5+21]`  matrix:

```
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

and a `[1 ,5]` matrix:

```
1 1 1 1 1
```

that reshaped to a `[7 , 23]` matrix.

Other solution using `repelem` + `bsxfun` +  `accumarray`:

```
r = repelem (1:7,5);
c= bsxfun(@plus, ((1:5)-3).',3*(1:7));
out = accumarray([r(:) c(:)] ,1)
```

Indices of rows and columns of `1` s  can be generated  and `accumarray` can be used to create the desired matrix.